sed with variable
I am using the sed command for replacing the text in a file and for that I am using variables in the sed command but it's not working. I have tried following the sed command with different options but nothing worked out. Please let me know if I am missing something.
old_title=[Enrolled' 'Population]' '(Overall' Study: Visits '1-5)
new_title=[Enrolled Population] (Visits 1-5, Contacts 1-2)


sed -i "s/$old_title/$new_title/g" file.txt
sed -i "s/${old_title}/${new_title}/g" file.txt

sed -i "s~$old_title~$new_title~g" file.txt
sed -i "/$old_title/c \\$new_title" file.txt

sed -i 's,"$old_title","$new_title" \0/,' file.txt


Show us a [mre] not snippets and include example input.  Your  variables assignment are not quoted properly, and you need to escape any regex special symbols.  If you mean bash with shell consider using the pattern replacement.  Also prefer writing to a new file and overwrite it when done.

Single quotes prevent bash from expanding variables.
